# How do I get a sleep potion?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The recent [version 3.25 update](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/15981-Version-3-25-release-notes) to Clash of Clans has a line item that says:

> Heroes recover health faster thanks to the Alchemists' new sleep potion

When I look in my Spell Factory after the update, I don't see any such potion - and sources I've checked online don't have any information on it.  Is this just a cute "canon" way of explaining the patch detail, or is the sleep potion a real thing you can purchase/create?  Also, what is the new rate of health regen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that after some investigation, this is just the developer's cute/canon way of explaining behavior changes in the release notes.  There are no "Alchemist's" or "sleep potions" to interact with in the game.  The Heroes rest time has been reduced across the board from 4 hours to 1 hour, with no other interaction/potions/etc required.